# Compile .AS Files through Flex 4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mxmlc

I've got the environment variables in Win7 set-up so that I can compile .as files through prompt.

But it shows some warning about not having FactoryClass, so I can't compile using shared libraries. How can I compile the file with classes and libraries imported ?

I'm trying to compile with `mxmlc file.as`

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
Warning: This compilation unit did not have a factoryClass specified in Frame metadata to load the configured runtime shared libraries. To compile without runtime shared libraries either set the -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries option to true or remove the -runtime-shared-libraries option.
```

Find the flex-config.xml file under the "frameworks" directory where you saved the Flex 4 files, and change the following from "false" to "true":

```
<static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>false</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>
to -->
<static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>true</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>
```

I'm on a Linux box here, but this should also do the trick on a Windows platform as well.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this into your compile time options, for example;

```
mxmlc -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true source.as
```